# How to find OEM Parts

Tags: parts, oem

I was curious if there was a database somewhere that, given any vehicle, would list the OEM manufacturer for any part that you need.

For example, I have a 2008 Toyota Camry Hybrid and my down stream Oxygen Sensor went bad.  Instead of buying the part from the dealership (which looks to be about $187), I was wondering what the OEM manufacturer of the part is, so I can buy that brand possibly cheaper on their own website or Amazon or another place.  I don't want to buy after market or stuff from Autozone, etc.  I would like the OEM brand for this part.  I've searched and can't find any such resource on the internet.

Comment: Get the part number from the dealer or the manufacturer  and search for that  or compare it to listings on online auro parts retailers. Many online auto parts retailers listings say if it is OEM.

Comment: Also check on the part for the make or number, my car has Delphi stuff and Bosch is common as well across **many** makes of car...

Comment: Please note: I see a close vote on this question as being a "shopping question". I don't believe this qualifies, as the OP is asking how to find part numbers, not asking where to buy the part itself.

Comment: Toyota is probably denso or delphi.

Answer (score 1):

The greatest resource I've found for what you are talking about is a website called [RockAuto.com](https://www.rockauto.com/)

(NOTE: I have no affiliation with or interest in the website or the company listed.)

Yes, they sell parts, but they have a lot more information than that available on their website.

Here's what I do ...

I go to their website and look up the vehicle in question (whether mine or someone else's I may be working on, whatever.) Once there, I find the part in question. Let's use your vehicle as an example.

[image]

Once I've found the vehicle, I find the part.

[image]

You'll notice the website has four O2 sensors. Each one listed has in parens the phrase *Click Info Button for Alternate/OEM Part Numbers*. So, click on the Info button and lets see what happens.

[image]

Here is a list of all the part numbers associated with your downstream O2 sensor. You can then take these numbers and cross-reference them using Google or your favorite search engine. You'll most likely want to put something like "O2 Sensor" along with the number, or maybe your car information (ie: 2008 Toyota Camry Hybrid <*sensor part number*>).

This may not always work, however, I'd give it in the neighborhood of 90+% of the time looking on here provides me with a part number I can use. Once you have the part number, you can use it to find your part at the best price possible.

On a separate note, I get you might like to get OEM O2 sensors for your vehicle. You can usually get replacement O2 sensors just or good or better than stock from the aftermarket. In most cases, Bosch O2 sensors are among the best you can buy (you usually pay a bit more than generic ones, but they are good). Why are they good? [Because Bosch developed them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_sensor). They know what they're doing. My main point with this is, don't be hung up on OEM parts. In most cases OEM is good. Does that mean it's better than everything on the market? By no means. Do not be afraid to shop around. You can usually do better than stock (or at least as good as stock) at a much cheaper price.

Comment: Please note: RockAuto is a company based in the States. It provides the information I'm talking about for most vehicles/parts located in the States. It doesn't provide information for foreign (to the US) makes/models.

Comment: Cool website!  So when I click "Info", how do I tell which one of those part numbers are OEM?  Or are all of them OEM?  Also, in that screen shot, it shows 4 different brands labeled as OEM.  So, which one is the OEM of the part?

Comment: @mang - I don't believe any of them are marked as OEM. They are, however, OEM equivalent. As far as which numbers are OEM, you'd have to research. Each one of those numbers are either the ones for OEM parts or are OEM equivalents. Thing is, as I stated, you'd have to take the numbers and research them as to which that is. This is a rather long list of numbers. Most parts I deal with might have two or three associated. Also, certain manufacturers use a "typical" numbering system for all their parts. Once you get used to it, you can usually see those numbers in the list and go right to them.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a cross-reference that says which parts from other manufacturers will fit. My son is in the trade so has access , otherwise it might not be easy to find. An example : I needed a set of wheel lugs for a Nissan Titan, Nissan dealer was out. My son found the same lugs were used on a Mercury van made by Nissan. Interestingly the Titan lugs were about $ 2 + each, same lugs from Mercury were about $ 0.5 each, and they were in stock.

Comment: And some lugs are identical across makes - about to order a set for my car which is not a toyota but the lugs are from toyota...