# How do I identify a part number for a Nissan Pulsar

Tags: nissan, part-identification, parts, pulsar

I'm currently trying to find a replacement for a broken indicator stalk on my N15 Nissan Pulsar and am having a hard time finding it with wreckers.

I know there is probably a low chance of this, but was wondering if there is any way to find the specific part number for the indicator stalk so I can go to a Nissan dealership to potentially get a replacement through them.

Thanks for any advice on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask the at the parts counter of a Nissan dealer.

You might also have success searching for the part on eBay. By specifying the model and year of the vehicle, eBay will return a listing of available parts, and many of those listings will contain Nissan's part number.

EDIT: The answer to [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/76730/how-to-find-oem-parts?rq=1) contains another very good tactic for finding the OEM part number: going to [Rockauto.com](https://www.rockauto.com/) and searching for the party by type.